# (com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions)' on a null object reference

Tags: android, google-maps, nullpointerexception

### MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.neetu.mapexample;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    GoogleMap googleMap;
    MarkerOptions markerOptions;
    LatLng latLng;
    EditText etLocation;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);


        Button btn_find = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_find);
        etLocation = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_location);

        View.OnClickListener findClickListener = new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                String location = etLocation.getText().toString();

                if(location!=null && !location.equals("")){
                    new GeocoderTask().execute(location);
                }
            }
        };
        btn_find.setOnClickListener(findClickListener);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        //getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap)
    {

    }

    private class GeocoderTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, List<Address>>
    {

        @Override
        protected List<Address> doInBackground(String... locationName)
        {
            // Creating an instance of Geocoder class
            Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getBaseContext());
            List<Address> addresses = null;

            try {
                // Getting a maximum of 3 Address that matches the input text
                addresses = geocoder.getFromLocationName(locationName[0], 3);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, (CharSequence) addresses, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return addresses;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<Address> addresses)
        {

            if(addresses==null || addresses.size()==0)
            {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No Location found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            // Clears all the existing markers on the map
            //googleMap.clear();

            // Adding Markers on Google Map for each matching address
            for(int i=0;i<addresses.size();i++){

                Address address = (Address) addresses.get(i);

                // Creating an instance of GeoPoint, to display in Google Map
                latLng = new LatLng(address.getLatitude(), address.getLongitude());

                String addressText = String.format("%s, %s",
                        address.getMaxAddressLineIndex() > 0 ? address.getAddressLine(0) : "",
                        address.getCountryName());

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, addressText, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title(addressText));
                if(i==0)
                    googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_find"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/str_btn_find"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/et_location"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:hint="@string/hnt_et_location"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/btn_find" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />

</LinearLayout>
```

### AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.neetu.mapexample">

    <!--
         The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
         Google Maps Android API v2, but you must specify either coarse or fine
         location permissions for the 'MyLocation' functionality. 
    -->

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!--
             The API key for Google Maps-based APIs is defined as a string resource.
             (See the file "res/values/google_maps_api.xml").
             Note that the API key is linked to the encryption key used to sign the APK.
             You need a different API key for each encryption key, including the release key that is used to
             sign the APK for publishing.
             You can define the keys for the debug and release targets in src/debug/ and src/release/. 
        -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MapsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_maps"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

> I try to mark and display the place by input place name in the edit
>   text but here error occur. Please help me.

### Logcat:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.addMarker(com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions)'
>   on a null object reference
>   at
>   com.example.neetu.mapexample.MainActivity$GeocoderTask.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:119)
>   at
>   com.example.neetu.mapexample.MainActivity$GeocoderTask.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:73)

Comment: Thankyou sir for suggestion. I read answers of linked question but not found any solution then i asked the question. Next time i read more carefully those answers to learn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because you haven't assigned value to the `googleMap` field yet. Update its value when it is ready.

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap){
    this.googleMap = googleMap;
}
```

Also add `googleMap != null` contition in your click listener.

```
if(googleMap!=null && location!=null && !location.equals("")){
    new GeocoderTask().execute(location);
}
```